# Wordpress page slow but nothing in mysql slow query

Tags: mysql, wordpress, performance

I have set long_query_time to 0.5, restarted MySQL and tested a page, it is slow but seeing nothing in the slow query log. What else can I look?

Comment: check if slow log worked with query like this : SELECT 1, sleep(2) FROM DUAL;

Comment: See this plugin for speeding up some of the queries:  [_WP Index Improvements_](https://wordpress.org/plugins/index-wp-mysql-for-speed/)

Answer (score 0):

The [Query Monitor plugin](https://querymonitor.com/) will be tremendously helpful for identifying why your site is slow. The plugin shows all SQL queries, highlights slow queries, and has profiling tools to help you identify where slow downs occur.